# Possible to move the tmp directory of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, performance, move, temporary-directory

I'm trying to speed up Eclipse by having my projects on a RAM disk (stuck with a slow laptop and a heavy kind of eclipse project at the moment). Worked great for loading the project and such, but when I'm building it seems to read and write a lot to a directory in %APPDATA% (seems to have a generated name from the name of the project). This makes it actually go slower than usual...

So... is there a way I can move the tmp directory of eclipse? Preferably without moving the tmp directory of other applications in the process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

May have found a way by setting a property called `java.io.tmpdir` in *eclipse.ini*. Seems to have changed where most of the read/write activity happens during build at least. For example:

```
-vmargs
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
-Djava.io.tmpdir=E:\tmp
```

Not sure if it have to be after the -vmargs thing or not, but this seems to work anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by Djava.io.tmpdir property  
->On root directory of your project right click as select run or debug as then in: 
In Run/Debug Configuration of your project   
->Run configuration  
->Arguments-->  
In VM Arguments  
write the complete path of your temp directory   
example: if you want to select a folder **JAVAtmp** in **F drive**  then pass the VM arguments as :  

**-Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\JAVATmp**