# Where is the temporary directory/location of eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jvisualvm, temporary-directory

I tried to fix a problem with jvisualvm not detecting local java applications as explained at
[Why won't the VisualVM Profiler profile my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296258/why-wont-the-visualvm-profiler-profile-my-application)

Unfortunately I could not find where the tmpdir of eclipse is.
Where is the java.io.tmpdir of eclipse?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328944/possible-to-move-the-tmp-directory-of-eclipse

Comment: this is nice. instead searching for it i set it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open Help > About Eclipse 
Click on "Installation Details" and then on the "Configuration" tab.
Wait until it has populated and scroll down a bit.
There you'll see amongst other things (with whatever value you have...):

java.io.tmpdir=/tmp

Comment: Yes, the above answer is helpful